# Pandas: Fillna in the column with the value of the same group

Tags: pandas, fillna

I need to fill null values in the column with not null value of the same group.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REtBL.png)

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkIrY.png)

I tried using transform with mode, but it didn't do the job.

```
test['col2']=test['col2'].transform(lambda x:x.fillna(x.mode())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `.assign` and `.apply` to go through each row and then find the mode:

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'col1':['gr1', 'gr2', 'gr1', 'gr1', 'gr2', 'gr3', 'gr2', numpy.nan], 
    'col2':['test1', 'test2', 'test', numpy.nan, numpy.nan, 'test3', numpy.nan, numpy.nan],
})

def fill_value(x):
    if x['col2'] is numpy.nan:
        mode = df.loc[df['col1'] == x['col1'], 'col2'].mode()
        default = numpy.nan
        return mode.iloc[0] if not mode.empty else default
    else:
        return x['col2']
    
df = df.assign(col2=df.apply(fill_value, axis=1))
```

output:

```
  col1   col2
0  gr1  test1
1  gr2  test2
2  gr1   test
3  gr1   test
4  gr2  test2
5  gr3  test3
6  gr2  test2
7  NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works on this example, however when I tried using this method on real Data Frame, I receive an error "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds".

Comment: This most likely means that you have a nan value in col2 that is also nan in col1.  I updated the code to check that there is a mode returned, else you can fill with a default value.

Comment: @Amistreem - Another solution working?

Comment: It does. I also tried your approach and it works too... Thank you.

Comment: @Amistreem - only one answer should be accepted, not both. Problem is in some group is only only missing values in `col2`, so raise error `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` if not use `next` + `iter` in my siolution for prevent this error.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `mode` and select first value if exist, else `None`, last pass to [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: next(iter(x.mode()), None))
df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(s)
print (df)
  col1   col2
0  gr1  test1
1  gr2  test2
2  gr1  test1
3  gr1  test1
4  gr2  test2
5  gr3  test3
6  gr2  test2
```

Comment: I think this answer would be more performant on a large dataset because you are iterating through the groups instead of the entire dataframe.  Pretty neat!